# Get full javascript date from passing a day (number), month (name), year (number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, logic

I'm trying to pass some date information to a date object to format the date based on where the user is hovering in a datepicker.

Using $(this) I'm able to get the day of the given month as a number. Using traversal i'm able to get the month name (February) and the year as a digit (2014).

Is it possible to take these values and apply them to a UTC date string so I can compare with my datepicker?

So far i've got:

```
var day = $(this).text();
var month = closest_datepicker.find('span.ui-datepicker-month').text();
var year = closest_datepicker.find('span.ui-datepicker-year').text();
```

which outputs '17 February 2014'

and ... well i'm not sure exactly the next step from here but I want to format this so that I either get the same format as my other dates:

```
Wed Feb 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
```

or a millisecond value like this: `1391748657216`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or:

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March']
var day = '17'
var month = 'February';
var year = 2014;

var date = new Date(+year, $.inArray(month, months), +day); // $.inArray() is used instead of Array.indexOf() because of IE compatibility
console.log(date)
```

Comment: Thanks - will try the loop and also check out moment.js - I'd rather not add another library to do this one task but it might be my only option.

Comment: Thanks Arun, this does what I need it to do to solve my problem.